# Linux Container: Failed to set up id mapping

Tags: linux, containers, lxc, uid

lxc 20220302000315.323 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:lxc_spawn:1163 - Failed to set up id mapping.

Unprivileged container is not coming up with the below error in the container logs
lxc 20220302000315.323 ERROR    lxd - start.c:lxc_spawn:1163 -Failed to set up id mapping.
lxc 20220302000011.952 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:__lxc_start:1338 - Failed to spawn container "XXX".

I am unable to to know which ID is mismatched to resolve the issue.

How do I know which ID mapping is causing the issue and how to resolve it ?

I tried mapping the ids in "/etc/subgid" and "/etc/subuid" and putting few additional permissions in "/etc/group". But resulting in the same error.

Comment: please show the content of your ```/etc/subuid``` and /etc/subgid```

with unprivileged containers, you have to start the containers with

```systemd-run --user --scope -p "Delegate=yes" lxc-start -n "$CONTAINER_NAME"``` where "$CONTAINER_NAME" is the name of the container.

then, you have mappings specific to the container itself in the config file of your container, please post the content of that also.

Comment: There are many ids being mapped and hence wanted to know any command to pin point the ids. But below are your requested entries.

subgid mapping
lxd:100000:10
lxd:200000:10
lxd:300000:10
lxd:400000:10
lxd:500000:10
lxd:600000:10
lxd:700000:10
lxd:800000:10
lxd:900000:10
lxd:1100000:10
lxd:9011:11
lxd:20:1
lxd:29:1
lxd:2005:1
lxd:2080:3
lxd:2140:1
lxd:4000:1
lxd:10600:4
lxd:10800:1
lxd:14030:1
lxd:17013:1
lxd:17025:1

Comment: subuid mapping
lxd:100000:10
lxd:200000:10
lxd:300000:10
lxd:400000:10
lxd:500000:10
lxd:600000:10
lxd:700000:10
lxd:800000:10
lxd:900000:10
lxd:1100000:10
lxd:9011:11
lxd:10800:1
lxd:14030:1
lxd:17013:1
lxd:17025:1

Comment: UID and GID mappings present in config file. 
lxc.id_map = u 0 1600000 106
lxc.id_map = g 0 1600000 106
lxc.id_map = u 9029 9029 1
lxc.id_map = g 9029 9029 1
lxc.id_map = u 9012 9012 1
lxc.id_map = g 9012 9012 1
lxc.id_map = g 2022 2022 1
lxc.id_map = u 2140 2140 4
lxc.id_map = g 2140 2140 4
lxc.id_map = u 10000 10000 400
lxc.id_map = g 10000 10000 400
lxc.id_map = u 65534 65534 1
lxc.id_map = g 65534 65534 1

Answer (score 0):

your mappings look quite wrong... syntax should be :

`/etc/subuid`

[local unprivileged user on the host that will run the container]:[uid on the host start at(this is inexisting uid on the host and it is ok)]:[number/range of uid to map]

e.g :
toto:100000:65535

`/etc/subuid`

[local unprivileged group on the host that will run the container]:[guid on the host start at(this is inexisting gid on the host and it is ok)]:[number/range of uid to map]

e.g :
toto:100000:65535

`config`

then, in the config file of the container, if you want to restrict the access further, you can do some specific mappings:

lxc.idmap = u 0 100000 1

lxc.idmap = g 0 100000 1

lxc.idmap = u 33 100033 1

lxc.idmap = g 33 100033 1

will map the uid and gid 0 (root) in the container to uid and gid 100000 on the host

will map the uid and gid 33 (www-data) in the container to uid and gid 100033 on the host

Comment: Added below in subgid file
lxd:1600000:106
lxd:9029:1
lxd:9012:1
lxd:2022:1
lxd:2140:4
lxd:10000:400
lxd:65534:1


Added below in subuid file
lxd:1600000:106
lxd:9029:1
lxd:9012:1
lxd:2140:4
lxd:10000:400
lxd:65534:1

Still encountering the same error

Comment: is lxd the user running the container?

can you explain why you map 106 ports on the container starting on the host at 1600000 with : lxd:1600000:106 ?

Comment: There are multiple processes running inside the container for which these uids are required to be mapped.